# How do you add two Class Member Functions together with another function inside the same class?

Tags: c++, class

#### I have two functions in my class, we'll say:

```
double MyClass::FunctionOne() {
    double Number = 1.5;
    return Number;
}
```

and

```
double MyClass::FunctionTwo(double x, double y, double z, double w) {
    total = x+y+z+w;
    return total;
}
```

*assume that "total" is a double declared in the class header*

How exactly do I add the returned values of both of these functions after my object has been instantiated in main?

#### In main, we'll assume it looks like this:

```
MyClass Object();
std::cout << "Function One: " << Object.FunctionOne()
          << "Function Two: " << Object.FunctionTwo(1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4);
```

Is there a way to sum these two functions in a separate function inside the class? And then call it using an accessor or something? Or must I do it like this:

```
double CombineFunctions(double x, double y) {
    double total2 = (x + y);
    return total2;
}

std::cout << "Sum of both functions: " 
<< CombineFunctions(Object.FunctionOne(), Object.FunctionTwo(1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4));
```

I'm fairly new at C++, so I don't actually know how to do this. I tried researching for a few hours but couldn't really find anything or wrap my head around it.

What I've tried: The closest I've got was declaring two variables in the class, then using them inside the class functions, and attempting to return them as:

```
double MyClass::SumOfReturns() {
    return total1 + total2;
}
```

but the number I received was what I think was a memory location? *163423e19* or something.

Comment: Why "in a separate function"? What's wrong with simply summing those two functions, as in `Object.FunctionOne() + Object.FunctionTwo(1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the results in class's members, and you can store the results in variables inside your main function:

```
MyClass Object();
double res1, res2;
res1 = Object.FunctionOne();
res2 = Object.FunctionTwo(1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4);
std::cout << "Function One: " << res1 << "Function Two: " << res2 << std::endl;
std::cout << "Sum of both functions: " << res1 + res2 << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the header of your class you can add sunch a function:

```
inline double MyClass::SumOfReturns() {
    return function1() + total;
}
```